# Controlling AWS RDS Posgres Failover Conditions/Criteria

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, failover

Here is the problem I am dealing with AWS RDS Postgres:

RDS Postgres instance is failing over and restarting. I know why: high swap and low memory. But I'm trying to find (and ideally change/override) the exact criteria that AWS is using to determine the condition/reason to fail-over. I've searched online and the config, nothing.

Can anyone with experience/knowledge of AWS RDS fail-over help?

Best Regards,
Michael

Comment: you can't change that criteria

Comment: Thank you for responding Mark! Do you happen to know if that criteria is documented and where? What exactly is it?